# Ruby Mastermind game project with AI

Tags: beginner, game, ruby

I'm self-learning and pretty new to coding and created a Mastermind game in Ruby.
Any general feedback or advice whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.
The game is completely functional right now, and has a simple AI. At the beginning the player chooses which role they want to choose (codebreaker or code maker).

Cheers

https://repl.it/repls/WeirdFrankButtons

edit: fixed link

````
class Game

  def initialize
    puts "---------------------------------"
    puts "Welcome to Mastermind"
    puts "The goal is to either create a 4 digit code (Code maker role) containing numbers ranging from 1 through 6 or to guess a code (Codebreaker role) created by the computer within 12 turns to win."
    puts "After each guess you will be given an accuracy score indicating how close you were to guessing the code correctly."
    puts "The letter \"H\" indicates one of the numbers you guessed is in the correct position. The letter \"h\" indicates you guessed a correct number but it is NOT in the correct position"
    puts "----------------------------------"
    @game_over = false
    @turn = 1
    until @comp_guess_mode === "Y" || @comp_guess_mode === "N"
      print "Is the computer the code breaker? Y/N"
      @comp_guess_mode = gets.chomp.upcase
    end
    game_mode
    turn_sequence
  end

  def game_mode
    if @comp_guess_mode == "Y"
      human_code_generator
    else
      code_generator
    end
  end

  def code_generator
    @code = Array.new(4) {rand(1..6)}
  end

  def human_code_generator
    @code = ""
    puts "Please enter a 4 digit code"
    until @code.length == 4
      @code = gets.chomp.each_char.map(&:to_i)
    end
  end
# computer_guesser method that tests if the computer's guess matches the human's
# by iterating through the array, if a direct match ('H') is found it will keep that number in the next guess
  def computer_guesser
    @updated_comp_guess = [" "," "," "," "]
    if @turn == 1
      @guess = Array.new(4) {rand(1..6)}
    else
      i = 0
      while i <4
        if @guess[i] == @code[i]
          @updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i]
          i+=1
        else
          i +=1
        end
      end
    end
      @guess = Array.new(4) {rand(1..6)}
      @updated_comp_guess.each_with_index do |value, idx|
        if value != " "
          @guess[idx] = value
        end
      end
      puts "Guess: #{@guess.join}"
  end


  def codebreaker_guess
    @guess = []
    until @guess.length == 4
      puts "Enter your 4 digit guess"
      @guess = gets.chomp.each_char.map(&:to_i)
      puts "Guess: #{@guess.join}"
      if @guess.length != 4
        print "Your guess was not 4 digits long, please guess again \n"
      end
    end
  end

  def turn_display
    puts "-------------------------"
    puts "It's turn number: #{@turn}" 
  end

  #Repeats the following guess/check sequence for 12 turns
  # or until the code and guess are matched
  def turn_sequence
    while @turn <13 && @game_over == false
      turn_display
      if @comp_guess_mode == "Y"
        computer_guesser
      else
        codebreaker_guess
      end       
      guess_checker
      @turn += 1
      victory_check
    end
  end

  def guess_checker
    @guess_accuracy = []
    @i=0
    @h_counter = 0
    while @i<4
      if @guess[@i] == @code[@i]
        @guess_accuracy.push("H")
        @h_counter += 1
        @i+=1
      else
        @i+=1
      end
    end
    if @i == 4
      i = 0
      compare_array = @code.clone
      while i < 4
        if compare_array.include?(@guess[i]) 
          compare_array[(compare_array.index(@guess[i]))]= " "
          @guess_accuracy.push("h")
          i+=1
        else
          i+=1
       end
      end
    @guess_accuracy.pop(@h_counter)
    puts "Guess accuracy: #{@guess_accuracy.join}"
    end
  end


  def victory_check
    if @guess[0..3] == @code[0..3]
      puts "Code was guessed correctly, it's #{@code}, codebreaker wins"
      @game_over = true
    elsif @turn == 13 && @game_over == false
      puts "Code was not guessed correctly, code maker wins"
      @game_over = true
    end
  end

end

game = Game.new

```
````

Answer (score 2):

**Code 1**

```
while i <4
    if @guess[i] == @code[i]
      @updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i]
      i+=1
    else
      i +=1
    end
  end
```

In both the `if` and `else` you are incrementing `i` by 1. That can be made shorter.

```
while i <4
    if @guess[i] == @code[i]
      @updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i]
    end
    i += 1
  end
```

Similar in the `guess_checker` further down, and in the `compare_array`

Answer (score 2):

## Consistency

Sometimes you are using 1 space for indentation, sometimes you are using 2. Sometimes you are using whitespace around operators, sometimes you don't, sometimes you are using whitespace on one side of the operator, but not the other. Sometimes, you use space after a comma, sometimes you don't. Sometimes you use one empty line after a method, sometimes two, sometimes none.

You should choose one style and stick with it. If you are editing some existing code, you should adapt your style to be the same as the existing code. If you are part of a team, you should adapt your style to match the rest of the team.

Most communities have developed standardized community style guides. In Ruby, there are multiple such style guides. They all agree on the basics (e.g. indentation is 2 spaces), but they might disagree on more specific points (single quotes or double quotes).

## Indentation

The standard indentation style in Ruby is two spaces. You mostly use 2 spaces, but there is one place where you use 1 space. Stick with two.

## Whitespace around operators

There should be 1 space either side of an operator. You sometimes use 1 space, sometimes no space, and sometimes space only on one side.

For example here, you have the exact same expression within three lines with two different spacing styles:

```rb
  i+=1
else
  i +=1
```

They are inconsistent with each, and both of them don't comply with community guidelines. They should both be:

```rb
  i += 1
```

## Space after comma

There should be 1 space after a comma. You sometimes use 1 space, sometimes no space.

E.g. here:

```rb
@updated_comp_guess = [" "," "," "," "]
```

should be

```rb
@updated_comp_guess = [" ", " ", " ", " "]
```

## Space in blocks

In a block literal, there should be a space after the opening curly brace and one before the closing curly brace:

```rb
@code = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
```

## Single-quoted strings

If you don't use string interpolation, it is helpful if you use single quotes for your strings. That way, it is immediately obvious that no string interpolation is taking place.

In particular, this would also remove the escaping you need to do here:

```rb
puts 'The letter "H" indicates one of the numbers you guessed is in the correct position. The letter "h" indicates you guessed a correct number but it is NOT in the correct position'
```

## Frozen string literals

Immutable data structures and purely functional code are always preferred, unless mutability and side-effects are required for clarity or performance. In Ruby, strings are always mutable, but there is a magic comment you can add to your files (also available as a command-line option for the Ruby engine), which will automatically make all literal strings immutable:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

It is generally preferred to add this comment to all your files.

## Conditional modifiers

When you have a conditional that executes only one expression, you should use the modifier form instead, e.g. this:

```rb
if value != " "
  @guess[idx] = value
end
```

should be

```rb
@guess[idx] = value if value != " "
```

Same here:

```rb
until @code.length == 4
  @code = gets.chomp.each_char.map(&:to_i)
end
```

should be

```rb
@code = gets.chomp.each_char.map(&:to_i) until @code.length == 4
```

## Unnecessary parentheses

```rb
compare_array[(compare_array.index(@guess[i]))]= " "
```

The parentheses around `compare_array.index(@guess[i])` are unnecessary.

## Linting

You should run some sort of linter or static analyzer on your code. [Rubocop](https://www.rubocop.org/) is a popular one, but there are others.

Rubocop was able to detect all of the style violations I pointed out, and also was able to autocorrect all of them.

Let me repeat that: I have just spent two pages pointing out how to correct tons of stuff that you can *actually* correct within milliseconds at the push of a button. I have set up my editor such that it automatically runs Rubocop with auto-fix as soon as I hit "save".

In particular, running Rubocop on your code, it detects 98 offenses, of which it can automatically correct 76. This leaves you with 22 offenses, of which 11 are very simple.

Here's what the result of the auto-fix looks like:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Game
  def initialize
    puts '---------------------------------'
    puts 'Welcome to Mastermind'
    puts 'The goal is to either create a 4 digit code (Code maker role) containing numbers ranging from 1 through 6 or to guess a code (Codebreaker role) created by the computer within 12 turns to win.'
    puts 'After each guess you will be given an accuracy score indicating how close you were to guessing the code correctly.'
    puts 'The letter "H" indicates one of the numbers you guessed is in the correct position. The letter "h" indicates you guessed a correct number but it is NOT in the correct position'
    puts '----------------------------------'
    @game_over = false
    @turn = 1
    until @comp_guess_mode === 'Y' || @comp_guess_mode === 'N'
      print 'Is the computer the code breaker? Y/N'
      @comp_guess_mode = gets.chomp.upcase
    end
    game_mode
    turn_sequence
  end

  def game_mode
    if @comp_guess_mode == 'Y'
      human_code_generator
    else
      code_generator
    end
  end

  def code_generator
    @code = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
  end

  def human_code_generator
    @code = ''
    puts 'Please enter a 4 digit code'
    @code = gets.chomp.each_char.map(&:to_i) until @code.length == 4
  end

  # computer_guesser method that tests if the computer's guess matches the human's
  # by iterating through the array, if a direct match ('H') is found it will keep that number in the next guess
  def computer_guesser
    @updated_comp_guess = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
    if @turn == 1
      @guess = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
    else
      i = 0
      while i < 4
        if @guess[i] == @code[i]
          @updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i]
          i += 1
        else
          i += 1
        end
      end
    end
    @guess = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
    @updated_comp_guess.each_with_index do |value, idx|
      @guess[idx] = value if value != ' '
    end
    puts "Guess: #{@guess.join}"
  end

  def codebreaker_guess
    @guess = []
    until @guess.length == 4
      puts 'Enter your 4 digit guess'
      @guess = gets.chomp.each_char.map(&:to_i)
      puts "Guess: #{@guess.join}"
      print "Your guess was not 4 digits long, please guess again \n" if @guess.length != 4
    end
  end

  def turn_display
    puts '-------------------------'
    puts "It's turn number: #{@turn}"
  end

  # Repeats the following guess/check sequence for 12 turns
  # or until the code and guess are matched
  def turn_sequence
    while @turn < 13 && @game_over == false
      turn_display
      if @comp_guess_mode == 'Y'
        computer_guesser
      else
        codebreaker_guess
      end
      guess_checker
      @turn += 1
      victory_check
    end
  end

  def guess_checker
    @guess_accuracy = []
    @i = 0
    @h_counter = 0
    while @i < 4
      if @guess[@i] == @code[@i]
        @guess_accuracy.push('H')
        @h_counter += 1
        @i += 1
      else
        @i += 1
      end
    end
    if @i == 4
      i = 0
      compare_array = @code.clone
      while i < 4
        if compare_array.include?(@guess[i])
          compare_array[compare_array.index(@guess[i])] = ' '
          @guess_accuracy.push('h')
          i += 1
        else
          i += 1
       end
      end
      @guess_accuracy.pop(@h_counter)
      puts "Guess accuracy: #{@guess_accuracy.join}"
    end
  end

  def victory_check
    if @guess[0..3] == @code[0..3]
      puts "Code was guessed correctly, it's #{@code}, codebreaker wins"
      @game_over = true
    elsif @turn == 13 && @game_over == false
      puts 'Code was not guessed correctly, code maker wins'
      @game_over = true
    end
  end
end

game = Game.new
```

And here are the offenses that Rubocop could not automatically correct:

```
Offenses:

game.rb:3:1: C: Metrics/ClassLength: Class has too many lines. [116/100]
class Game ...
^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:3:1: C: Style/Documentation: Missing top-level class documentation comment.
class Game
^^^^^
game.rb:4:3: C: Metrics/MethodLength: Method has too many lines. [14/10]
  def initialize ...
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:7:121: C: Layout/LineLength: Line is too long. [202/120]
    puts 'The goal is to either create a 4 digit code (Code maker role) containing numbers ranging from 1 through 6 or to guess a code (Codebreaker role) created by the computer within 12 turns to win.'
                                                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:8:121: C: Layout/LineLength: Line is too long. [125/120]
    puts 'After each guess you will be given an accuracy score indicating how close you were to guessing the code correctly.'
                                                                                                                        ^^^^^
game.rb:9:121: C: Layout/LineLength: Line is too long. [186/120]
    puts 'The letter "H" indicates one of the numbers you guessed is in the correct position. The letter "h" indicates you guessed a correct number but it is NOT in the correct position'
                                                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:13:28: C: Style/CaseEquality: Avoid the use of the case equality operator ===.
    until @comp_guess_mode === 'Y' || @comp_guess_mode === 'N'
                           ^^^
game.rb:13:56: C: Style/CaseEquality: Avoid the use of the case equality operator ===.
    until @comp_guess_mode === 'Y' || @comp_guess_mode === 'N'
                                                       ^^^
game.rb:41:3: C: Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for computer_guesser is too high. [<12, 12, 11> 20.22/17]
  def computer_guesser ...
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:41:3: C: Metrics/MethodLength: Method has too many lines. [19/10]
  def computer_guesser ...
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:50:11: C: Style/IdenticalConditionalBranches: Move i += 1 out of the conditional.
          i += 1
          ^^^^^^
game.rb:52:11: C: Style/IdenticalConditionalBranches: Move i += 1 out of the conditional.
          i += 1
          ^^^^^^
game.rb:80:3: C: Metrics/MethodLength: Method has too many lines. [11/10]
  def turn_sequence ...
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:94:3: C: Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for guess_checker is too high. [<16, 13, 11> 23.37/17]
  def guess_checker ...
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:94:3: C: Metrics/MethodLength: Method has too many lines. [27/10]
  def guess_checker ...
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
game.rb:102:9: C: Style/IdenticalConditionalBranches: Move @i += 1 out of the conditional.
        @i += 1
        ^^^^^^^
game.rb:104:9: C: Style/IdenticalConditionalBranches: Move @i += 1 out of the conditional.
        @i += 1
        ^^^^^^^
game.rb:107:5: C: Style/GuardClause: Use a guard clause (return unless @i == 4) instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression.
    if @i == 4
    ^^
game.rb:114:11: C: Style/IdenticalConditionalBranches: Move i += 1 out of the conditional.
          i += 1
          ^^^^^^
game.rb:116:11: C: Style/IdenticalConditionalBranches: Move i += 1 out of the conditional.
          i += 1
          ^^^^^^
game.rb:117:8: W: Layout/EndAlignment: end at 117, 7 is not aligned with if at 111, 8.
       end
       ^^^
game.rb:135:1: W: Lint/UselessAssignment: Useless assignment to variable - game.
game = Game.new
^^^^

1 file inspected, 22 offenses detected
```

Let's look at the simple ones first.

## Case equality operator

You use the case equality operator in a couple of places. Because of the way case equality is defined for strings, your code works purely "by accident". You should use the normal equality operator instead.

This:

```rb
until @comp_guess_mode === "Y" || @comp_guess_mode === "N"
```

should be this:

```rb
until @comp_guess_mode == "Y" || @comp_guess_mode == "N"
```

Note that you use the correct equality operator for the exact same check here:

```rb
if @comp_guess_mode == "Y"
```

## Identical expressions in all branches

There are three places where you have the same expression in both branches of a conditional expression. That is unnecessary clutter, you can just pull the expression out of the conditional:

```rb
if @guess[i] == @code[i]
  @updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i]
  i+=1
else
  i +=1
end
```

should be

```rb
if @guess[i] == @code[i]
  @updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i]
end

i +=1
```

And as we said above, a conditional with only one expression should use the modifier form (note that this transformation would again be performed automatically by Rubocop if you ran it again):

```rb
@updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i] if @guess[i] == @code[i]

i +=1
```

## Unused local variable

```rb
game = Game.new
```

`game` is never used anywhere. Just remove it:

```rb
Game.new
```

## Guard clauses

If you have a case where an entire method or block is wrapped in a conditional, you can replace that with a "guard clause" and reduce the level of nesting.

E.g. this:

```rb
def something
  if foo
    bar
    baz
    quux
  else
    42
  end
end
```

can become this:

```rb
def something
  return 42 unless foo

  bar
  baz
  quux
end
```

There are a couple of opportunities to do this in your code, and a couple more are created by following the Rubocop advice.

Here is one example where the improvement is not very big:

```rb
def game_mode
  if @comp_guess_mode == "Y"
    human_code_generator
  else
    code_generator
  end
end
```

```rb
def game_mode
  return human_code_generator if @comp_guess_mode == "Y"

  code_generator
end
```

but here the gain is somewhat bigger:

```rb
def guess_checker
  @guess_accuracy = []
  @i=0
  @h_counter = 0
  while @i<4
    if @guess[@i] == @code[@i]
      @guess_accuracy.push("H")
      @h_counter += 1
      @i+=1
    else
      @i+=1
    end
  end
  if @i == 4
    i = 0
    compare_array = @code.clone
    while i < 4
      if compare_array.include?(@guess[i]) 
        compare_array[(compare_array.index(@guess[i]))]= " "
        @guess_accuracy.push("h")
        i+=1
      else
        i+=1
     end
    end
  @guess_accuracy.pop(@h_counter)
  puts "Guess accuracy: #{@guess_accuracy.join}"
  end
end
```

```rb
def guess_checker
  @guess_accuracy = []
  @i = 0
  @h_counter = 0

  while @i < 4
    if @guess[@i] == @code[@i]
      @guess_accuracy.push('H')
      @h_counter += 1
    end
    @i += 1
  end

  return unless @i == 4

  i = 0
  compare_array = @code.clone

  while i < 4
    if compare_array.include?(@guess[i]) 
      compare_array[compare_array.index(@guess[i])]= ' '
      @guess_accuracy.push('h')
    end

    i += 1
  end

  @guess_accuracy.pop(@h_counter)
  puts "Guess accuracy: #{@guess_accuracy.join}"
end
```

## Redundant checks

But actually, the entire thing is even simpler: since you loop and increment `i` 4 times, it will *always* be `4`, so the condition will always be true and you can just remove it altogether.

## Equality with booleans

```rb
@game_over == false
```

`@game_over` is already a boolean, there is no need to check for equality to `false`. This is just

```rb
!@game_over
```

## Unnecessary instance variables

The instance variables `@updated_comp_guess`, `@i`, `@h_counter`, and `@guess_accuracy` are only ever used in one method. They should be local variables instead.

## Loops

In Ruby, you almost never need loops. In fact, I would go so far and say that if you are using a loop in Ruby, you are doing it wrong.

Here's an example:

```rb
i = 0
while i < 4
  updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i] if @guess[i] == @code[i]

  i += 1
end
```

would be much better written as

```rb
4.times do |i|
  updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i] if @guess[i] == @code[i]
end
```

This will make the `guess_checker` method look like this:

```rb
def guess_checker
  guess_accuracy = []
  h_counter = 0

  4.times do |i|
    if @guess[i] == @code[i]
      guess_accuracy.push('H')
      h_counter += 1
    end
  end

  compare_array = @code.clone

  4.times do |i|
    if compare_array.include?(@guess[i])
      compare_array[compare_array.index(@guess[i])] = ' '
      guess_accuracy.push('h')
    end
  end

  guess_accuracy.pop(h_counter)
  puts "Guess accuracy: #{guess_accuracy.join}"
end
```

which gives us again the opportunity to use guard clauses:

```rb
def guess_checker
  guess_accuracy = []
  h_counter = 0

  4.times do |i|
    next unless @guess[i] == @code[i]

    guess_accuracy.push('H')
    h_counter += 1
  end

  compare_array = @code.clone

  4.times do |i|
    next unless compare_array.include?(@guess[i])

    compare_array[compare_array.index(@guess[i])] = ' '
    guess_accuracy.push('h')
  end

  guess_accuracy.pop(h_counter)
  puts "Guess accuracy: #{guess_accuracy.join}"
end
```

## Redundant expressions

In `computer_guesser`, if `@turn == 1`, you initialize `@guess`, and then you initialize it again without ever using it in between. The first initialization can just be removed, turning this:

```rb
if @turn == 1
  @guess = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
else
  4.times do |i|
    updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i] if @guess[i] == @code[i]
  end
end

@guess = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
```

into this:

```rb
unless @turn == 1
  4.times do |i|
    updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i] if @guess[i] == @code[i]
  end
end

@guess = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
```

## Code duplication

```rb
Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
```

Appears multiple times in your code. It should be extracted into a method.

## `length` vs. `size`

Many Ruby collections have both `length` and `size` methods, but some have only one. In general, *IFF* a collection has a `size` method, then that method is guaranteed to be "efficient" (usually constant time), whereas `length` may or may not be efficient (linear time for iterating through the collection and counting all the elements), depending on the collection.

In your case, you are using arrays and strings, for which both are constant time, but if you want to guarantee efficiency, then it is better to explicitly use `size` instead.

## The Elephant in the room

One thing I have not addressed so far, and that I unfortunately do not have to time to address, is the fundamental design of the code. Everything I mentioned so far is just cosmetics.

All work is done in the initializer. All an initializer should do is initialize the object. It shouldn't ask for user input, it shouldn't print anything, it shouldn't play a game.

Also, you are mixing I/O and logic everywhere. A method should either print something or do something. Your design makes it impossible to test the code without actually playing the game. I cannot prepare a file with codes and guesses and feed it to a test runner, I actually have to manually play the game.

It is also strange that you have only one "object", namely the game, which is doing something. If you think about how the game is typically played, aren't the objects that are actively doing something the players and not the game? Where are the players in your design?

Unfortunately, I do not have time to dive into this.

Here is where the code currently stands:

````rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Game
  def initialize
    puts '---------------------------------'
    puts 'Welcome to Mastermind'
    puts 'The goal is to either create a 4 digit code (Code maker role) containing numbers ranging from 1 through 6 or to guess a code (Codebreaker role) created by the computer within 12 turns to win.'
    puts 'After each guess you will be given an accuracy score indicating how close you were to guessing the code correctly.'
    puts 'The letter "H" indicates one of the numbers you guessed is in the correct position. The letter "h" indicates you guessed a correct number but it is NOT in the correct position'
    puts '----------------------------------'

    @game_over = false
    @turn = 1

    until @comp_guess_mode == 'Y' || @comp_guess_mode == 'N'
      print 'Is the computer the code breaker? Y/N'
      @comp_guess_mode = gets.chomp.upcase
    end

    game_mode
    turn_sequence
  end

  def game_mode
    return human_code_generator if @comp_guess_mode == 'Y'

    code_generator
  end

  def code_generator
    @code = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
  end

  def human_code_generator
    @code = ''
    puts 'Please enter a 4 digit code'
    @code = gets.chomp.each_char.map(&:to_i) until @code.size == 4
  end

  # computer_guesser method that tests if the computer's guess matches the human's
  # by iterating through the array, if a direct match ('H') is found it will keep that number in the next guess
  def computer_guesser
    updated_comp_guess = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']

    unless @turn == 1
      4.times do |i|
        updated_comp_guess[i] = @guess[i] if @guess[i] == @code[i]
      end
    end

    @guess = Array.new(4) { rand(1..6) }
    updated_comp_guess.each_with_index do |value, idx|
      @guess[idx] = value if value != ' '
    end

    puts "Guess: #{@guess.join}"
  end

  def codebreaker_guess
    @guess = []

    until @guess.size == 4
      puts 'Enter your 4 digit guess'
      @guess = gets.chomp.each_char.map(&:to_i)
      puts "Guess: #{@guess.join}"
      print "Your guess was not 4 digits long, please guess again \n" if @guess.size != 4
    end
  end

  def turn_display
    puts '-------------------------'
    puts "It's turn number: #{@turn}"
  end

  # Repeats the following guess/check sequence for 12 turns
  # or until the code and guess are matched
  def turn_sequence
    while @turn < 13 && !@game_over
      turn_display
      if @comp_guess_mode == 'Y'
        computer_guesser
      else
        codebreaker_guess
      end
      guess_checker
      @turn += 1
      victory_check
    end
  end

  def guess_checker
    guess_accuracy = []
    h_counter = 0

    4.times do |i|
      next unless @guess[i] == @code[i]

      guess_accuracy.push('H')
      h_counter += 1
    end

    compare_array = @code.clone

    4.times do |i|
      next unless compare_array.include?(@guess[i])

      compare_array[compare_array.index(@guess[i])] = ' '
      guess_accuracy.push('h')
    end

    guess_accuracy.pop(h_counter)
    puts "Guess accuracy: #{guess_accuracy.join}"
  end

  def victory_check
    if @guess == @code
      puts "Code was guessed correctly, it's #{@code}, codebreaker wins"
      @game_over = true
    elsif @turn == 13 && !@game_over
      puts 'Code was not guessed correctly, code maker wins'
      @game_over = true
    end
  end
end

Game.new
```
````